# How do I determine the type of a record value from the type of another value in the same record?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a nested type like this:

```
type MessageType = {
  "sse": {
    "task.completed": { completedAt: Date };
    "task.created": { startedAt: Date };
  } 
};
```

used in a class like so:

```
class Subscriber<T extends keyof MessageType> {
  private dataStream$: Array<any> = new Array();

  nextItem<K extends keyof MessageType[T]>(): { event: K; data: MessageType[T][K]} {
    return this.dataStream$.pop();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to type `dataStream$` - the `nextItem` typing works correctly, enforcing that objects where `event: "task.completed"` expect the `data: { completedAt: new Date() }`.
I can't figure out how to alias `K` in the same way when its for the Array type, eg the following doesn't work:

```
private dataStream$: Array<{event: K extends keyof MessageType[T], data: MessageType[T][K]> = new Array();
```

Any guidance on how to properly type the `dataStream$` subject would be greatly appreciated!

[Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZQK4CMBWBTAxjAGjgHl0BnbKANwEN0AbbOAXzgDMoIQ4AiKAD0xkeAbgBQYmAE8wTALLYyZGgHNsAFRlMAvIjFwDcJdgBcewxd4waZANYA6XFGw0Y2ACY8zCfZb8xQRWtwMwARV2xxPwNmKOieaztHLjBGN09vX2jDMlQQEBooKTMyGChgADsVOL9YrJYxZglcehsyFAwyJ2B0SgAedThsfjcK93bbbCkINjgFJVUNLQA%20c0Mwcto3OHdXGmQylxAAEjM0LDwYPpoKqVXdCuwAdw6L-AAKAEpxetwICtKUFQ%20Gg7w2wC2TABZnUnzW-gAFsAyPZUBRkJQqJQMRUYABRLG494JGwOP7gNIeHhEd67azeIx5ApFEplSoqFhw7SrBDMb71Jr1XLkbq9PoAaSGI2wYwmUxmc0UyjUmlkAG11ABdZZfMykCjUOiMPpIbCEmBmcUiHZ7MzzZVLdVatXizXMHn1CzOGCoKAVOAwJEoun7Q40E41Br1NHYDHUbEy-HmiVS0bjOCTaaze2LVXYDXa95mxOWoi4Gj0ejoGi4WxmWm2xULFVaAsuzVc1ZUCDAdyfMzd3t6AUSQXvR4vc5dcq9KDE4w8T6fVHozEJ3EExPExJklKUzw0pC5fKFKScuDcxB8kRAA)

Comment: Do you want this question to depend on rxjs?  If so, you might want to tag it as such.  If not, then please remove references to rxjs typings so that your code forms a self-contained [mre].

Comment: What do you mean `when its not for a function though` ? could you please provide more context/examples?

Comment: Addressed both comments

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpD1Xm) meet your needs?  I think you want a union of possible values instead of one indexed by a type parameter.  I'm not sure how you expect `nextItem()` to work safely given that the type parameter `K` is specified by the *caller* and not the implementation.  Anyway let me know if that works for your use cases and I can write up an answer if so. Otherwise please [edit] the example to demonstrate unsatisfied use cases.  Oh, and if you're going to reply in a comment, please @jcalz me, or I might not be notified (I just happened to come back this time)

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the assist - looks like the actual thing I was looking for was: ```type SSEMessageItem<K extends keyof MessageType> =
    { [k: K]: {
        [P in keyof MessageType[K]]: { event: P; data: MessageType[K][P] }
    }[keyof MessageType[K]]``` - couldn't have gotten there without you though! In response to your comment on the `pop` on the array, yes, it wouldn't be guaranteed - this is really for an RxJS stream, but the typing implementation didn't depend on it being RxJS

Comment: That's not valid TypeScript (`{[k: K]: ...}` ) but the part that is valid looks (checks IDE) the same as what I put in there.  So do you want me to write up an answer explaining how my thing works?  Or do you have some unmet need that corresponds to whatever `{[k: K]: ...}` is doing?

Comment: hey @jcalz, you're right - my IDE isn't complaining at the typedef anymore (which is odd) but it is complaining later on when I'm actually trying to process the items - yeah, if you wouldn't mind writing a quick explanation I'd really appreciate it!